# Loop combinations of byte for Poker simulator

Tags: c#, .net, simulation, iteration

In (this) Poker you have 2 hole cards that are combined with 5 shared cards on the board. Each player makes the best 5 card hand from the seven. Believe it or not that is over 2 billion runs to do them all.

I'm trying to create statistics for 2 known hole cards against random boards and random hands for a single opponent using Monte Carlo for like 20 million runs.

First get sets of 7 random for board plus 1 opponent from 50 (known 2 hole cards are removed).  From those 7 remove all 2 card combinations (21) to represent the opponent's hole cards.  The idea is better statistics with an exhaustive examination of the 7 rather than a random 5 and a random 2.  Computation on the random 5 plus random 2 is more efficient as you only need to run the known hand once for each random 5.

```
byte? skip1 = null;
byte? skip2 = null;
List<byte> deck50seven = null;
byte nextSevenLastStart = 42;
private IEnumerable<byte> NextSevenA(byte Skip1, byte Skip2)
{
    if (Skip1 == Skip2)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("skip1 == skip2");
    if (Skip1 > 51 || Skip2 > 51 || Skip1 < 0 || Skip2 < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("51 0");
    if(skip1 == null)
    {
        skip1 = Skip1;
        skip2 = Skip2;
        deck50seven = new List<byte>(50);
        for(byte b = 0; b < 52; b++)
        {
            if (b == Skip1 || b == Skip2)
                continue;
            deck50seven.Add(b);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Skip1 != skip1 || Skip2 != skip2)
            throw new ArgumentException("skippy");
    }
    if (nextSevenLastStart >= 42)
    {
        nextSevenLastStart = 0;
        // Yates shuffle
        for (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
        {   // int for indexing is faster (I think)
            int j = rand.Next(i + 1);  // it can get swapped with itself
            if (j != i)
            {   // exchange values
                byte curVal = deck50seven[i];
                deck50seven[i] = deck50seven[j];
                deck50seven[j] = curVal;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        nextSevenLastStart += 7;
    return deck50seven.GetRange(nextSevenLastStart, 7);
}
private IEnumerable<List<byte>> NextSevenAsFiveTwo(List<byte> input)
{
    // 21 ways to take 2 from 7 
    // this is going to seem strange but need every combination of 2 to be the last 2
    if (input.Count() != 7)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input.Count() != 7");
    List<byte> output = new List<byte>();
    for (byte i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (byte j = (byte)(i + 1); j <= 6; j++)
        {
            output.Clear();
            for (byte k = 0; k < 7; k++)
                if (k != i && k != j)
                    output.Add(input[k]);
            output.Add(input[i]);
            output.Add(input[j]);
            yield return output;
        }
    }
}
```

can use this for test

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    List<byte> nextSevenA = new List<byte>(NextSevenA(11, 12));
    Debug.WriteLine("Base " + string.Join(", ", nextSevenA));
    foreach(List<byte> ss in NextSevenAsFiveTwo(nextSevenA))
        Debug.WriteLine("     Subset " + string.Join(", ", ss));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### `private IEnumerable<byte> NextSevenA(byte Skip1, byte Skip2)`

- Method arguments should be named using `camelCase` casing. In this way you wouldn't mistake them for being properties.

  If you need the `PascalCase` casing of the arguments to distinguish them from your local variables, you should either change their names or use `this` for use with class level variables.
- Omitting braces although they might be optional, like for single lined `if` statements, can lead to serious bugs which are hard to find. I would like to encourage you to always use them. This not only makes your code less error prone but also more readable because it looks more structured.
- throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is a good thing but the error message should be more expressive. `"51 0"` isn't telling really much.
- You should validate

  > ```
  >     if (Skip1 != skip1 || Skip2 != skip2)
  >         throw new ArgumentException("skippy");
  > ```

  earlier to make it clear where the validation happens.
- by extracting the generation of the byte values of `deck50seven` to a separate method returning an `IEnumerable<byte>` the method could be shorter.

  ```
  private static IEnumerable<byte> GetByteRange(byte start, byte end)
  {
      for (byte b = start; b < end; b++)
      {
          yield return b;
      }
  }
  ```

  After introducing a `private const int MaxCardsInDeck = 52` this could be called like

  ```
  deck50seven = GetByteRange(0, MaxCardsInDeck).Except(new byte[] { Skip1, Skip2 }).ToList();
  ```
- By changing the way you handle `nextSevenLastStart` you could get rid of the `else` part at the end. I say **could** because I don't know if you somewhere else using that variable. The way I would do this is like so

  ```
  nextSevenLastStart += 7;
  if (nextSevenLastStart >= 49)
  {
      //shuffling now
  }
  ```

  If this isn't an option you should consider to invert the condition `if (nextSevenLastStart >= 42)` and return early which saves you one level of indentation.
- The shuffeling of the `deck50seven` should be extracted to a separate method like so

  ```
  private static Random rand = new Random();
  private static void Shuffle(List<byte> items, int upperBound=42,int lowerBound=1)
  {
      for (int i = upperBound; i >= lowerBound; i--)
      {   
          int j = rand.Next(i + 1);  
          if (j != i)
          {  
              byte currentValue = items[i];
              items[i] = items[j];
              items[j] = currentValue;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- You have a lot of magic numbers in your code of which I am unsure what they are about so I will leave them untouched. You should extract them to meaningful constants.

Implementing the mentioned points apart from the exception messages, because I don't have enough context, will lead to

```
private IEnumerable<byte> NextSevenA(byte skip1, byte skip2)
{
    if (skip1 == skip2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("skip1 == skip2");
    }

    if (skip1 > 51 || skip2 > 51 || skip1 < 0 || skip2 < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("51 0");
    }

    if (this.skip1.HasValue && (this.skip1 != skip1 || this.skip2 != skip2))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("skippy");
    }

    if (skip1 == null)
    {
        this.skip1 = skip1;
        this.skip2 = skip2;
        deck50seven = GetByteRange(0, 52).Except(new byte[] { skip1, skip2 }).ToList();
    }

    nextSevenLastStart += 7;

    if (nextSevenLastStart >= 49)
    {
        nextSevenLastStart = 0;
        Shuffle(deck50seven);
    }

    return deck50seven.GetRange(nextSevenLastStart, 7);
}
```

---

### `private IEnumerable<List<byte>> NextSevenAsFiveTwo(List<byte> input)`

- Using the `Count()` extension method on a `List<T>` involves a (soft)cast to an `ICollection<T>` so it should be faster to just use the `Count` property.
- Because the method is only called by requesting the enumerator you should extract the validation of the `Count` property to a separate method. IMO this `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` should be thrown at the moment you call the method.
- Instead of the most inner loop and the check for `if (k != i && k != j)` you can use `Enumerable.Range()` excepting `i and j`. This range can be stored in a class level (but static) variable so we can make the method `static` as well.

Implementing the mentioned points will look like so

```
private static IEnumerable<List<byte>> NextSevenAsFiveTwo(List<byte> input)
{
    if (input.Count != 7)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input.Count != 7");
    }
    return NextSevenAsFiveTwoIterator(input);
}
private static IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(0, 7);
private static IEnumerable<List<byte>> NextSevenAsFiveTwoIterator(List<byte> input)
{
    // 21 ways to take 2 from 7 
    // this is going to seem strange but need every combination of 2 to be the last 2

    List<byte> output = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = (i + 1); j <= 6; j++)
        {
            output.Clear();
            foreach (int k in range.Except(new int[] { i, j }))
            {
                output.Add(input[k]);
            }
            output.Add(input[i]);
            output.Add(input[j]);
            yield return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of good stuff.  But.  I don't see how flopping nextSevenLastStart >= 42 would save an indent.   You signatures don't match on shuffle.  The lower bound on a yates shuffle is always 1 - that is how it works.  The upper bound is away the last item (count - 1).   I put in a 49 as count has to be 50 here.